# How to run multiple Test Group in single .jmx using jmeter

Tags: java, apache, jmeter

I have created one Test plan, and inside it have added 5 Test Group.
I am able to run 1 Test Group at a single time.
Is there any way, where 5 test group can be run in single jmx file ?

Comment: Do you mean "Thread Group"?

Answer (score 8):

Check "**Run Test Groups consecutively**" box status (under Test Plan properties). If you uncheck it you'll have all your thread groups running in parallel.

However you need to remember that variables cannot be passed between different thread groups and if your test logic assumes creating some entities in one thread group, reading them in another, editing in the third and deleting in the fourth you may wish to learn [how to pass variables and cookies between different thread groups](http://blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups).